# Into how many video formats should I convert uploaded videos to play in all media types?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing

I am planning on video upload capability on a public website.

I am not going with Flash instead going with HTML5 using MediaElement.js
My goal is to make sure that processed videos play on browser and all smart devices

I used to convert uploaded videos to flv file to play using flash.

I will use FFMPEG to convert uploaded videos to the target format.

My question is how many different format do I need to process\convert the uploaded files?

Comment: I'd personally go for HTML5 first, and have flash as a fallback for users with older browsers - I know flash is going, but we can't forget that some browsers don't even support HTML5 (like IE8 that XP users have to use if they don't use Firefox, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need at least 2 for the HTML5 video element. You need to supply a H264 and either Ogg or WebM. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) for the supported codexs.

I have never used MediaElement.js but it look like they can work with either of the two formats in browsers that don't support the  element.

Comment: Maurice: does this also mean that for each uploaded video, I need to create minimum 2 files for 2 format? This will double the space requirements. No?

Comment: Yes it does. I think it is really unfortunate that there isn't a single encoding all vendors support but that is the way it is right now. I really hope that will change in the future.

Comment: Maurice: one more question - what is the recommendation - create the mostly watched format firsthand and other formats dynamically when requested. I am little hesitant on creating 2/3 different files for same video. Little nightmare.

Comment: Video rendering is quite a computational expensive thing to do so rendering videos on demand is not really practical. And disk space is cheap. You could for instance use Azure and just pay for what you are using.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to play everything via HTML5 then YES, you do need 2 video-files for each video, as explained by Maurice.

BUT: You could use the Flash-fallback and only use mp4 videos (MEJS will take care of Flash). That way it plays on iOS, many Android devices and chrome, safari and IE9 via HTML5 - Firefox and Opera users will see the Flash-player.

Comment: Hi Jorn, You meant MediaElementJS by MEJS? It will save me from lots of hassle if I can produce just one file. Given the video file size, it scares me a bit if I need to create 2 files for each video.

Comment: yes, MEJS is short for MediaElement.js - actually I'm using the one-file-approach myself. But for some projects it might be good to show off with HTML5-players... that's really up to your client

Comment: I don't have any control over clients. They will be using IE6-IE9/FF/Chrome/Safari from pc while others will be using IOS, Android devices. MEJS will fall back to Flash if no HTML5. But I read somewhere people recommending 2 formats: MP4 and webm. One format working for all of your clients or you have some complaints from some clients?

Comment: if you use html5 AND flash as a fallback you currently only need mp4